# python regex capturing variables

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to create a data frame with variables `bidder_id`, `number_subcontractors`, and `items` using multiple txt files.

The sample text is as follows:

```
11/15/2022

                                        LIST OF SUBCONTRACTORS

BIDDER ID             NAME AND ADDRESS  LICENSE NUMBER          DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 5 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 7 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 11 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 31 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 89-97 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 6 (62%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 12 (81%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 15 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 16 (48%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              TRAFFIC CONTROL SYSTEM (PARTIAL)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              RADAR FEEDBACK (RENTAL)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

CONTINUED ON  NEXT PAGE
01-0H20U4                                                                                                    PAGE S2

01-HUM-101-75.9/79.5                                                                                         11/16/2022

11/15/2022

                                                    LIST OF SUBCONTRACTORS

BIDDER ID             NAME AND ADDRESS              LICENSE NUMBER          DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK   SUBCONTRACTED

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                                          ALT TEMP CRASH CUSHION (RENTAL)

                      ANDERSON CA                   983087

VC0000000213          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 1 (55%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000213          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 8-10 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000613          Okay MARKING                          ITEM 83 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000613          Okay MARKING                          ITEM 87-88 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 98-106 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          LCP (STRIPING ONLY)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 114 (1%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          MOB (STRIPE ONLY)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000813          BAY LINE CUTTING & CORING                             ITEM 33 (8%)

                      SAN FRANCISCO CA              809660
```

The ideal data frame would look something like this (with all the bidder IDs):

| bidder_id | number_subcontractors | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VC0000000213 | 2 | 5 (100%), 7(100%), 11 (100%), .... , 8-10 (100%) |
| VC0000000613 | 1 | 83(100%), 87-88 (100%) |

`number_subcontractors` is 2 for `bidder_id == VC0000000213` because there are two unique Name and Address values for the bidder id.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

document = '''11/15/2022

                                        LIST OF SUBCONTRACTORS

BIDDER ID             NAME AND ADDRESS  LICENSE NUMBER          DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 5 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 7 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 11 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 31 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 89-97 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 6 (62%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 12 (81%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 15 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              ITEM 16 (48%)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              TRAFFIC CONTROL SYSTEM (PARTIAL)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                              RADAR FEEDBACK (RENTAL)

                      ANDERSON CA       983087

CONTINUED ON  NEXT PAGE
01-0H20U4                                                                                                    PAGE S2

01-HUM-101-75.9/79.5                                                                                         11/16/2022

11/15/2022

                                                    LIST OF SUBCONTRACTORS

BIDDER ID             NAME AND ADDRESS              LICENSE NUMBER          DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK   SUBCONTRACTED

VC0000000213          T AND S DVBE                                          ALT TEMP CRASH CUSHION (RENTAL)

                      ANDERSON CA                   983087

VC0000000213          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 1 (55%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000213          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 8-10 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000613          Okay MARKING                          ITEM 83 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000613          Okay MARKING                          ITEM 87-88 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 98-106 (100%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          LCP (STRIPING ONLY)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          ITEM 114 (1%)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000713          SPECIALIZED PAVEMENT MARKING                          MOB (STRIPE ONLY)

                      ANDERSON CA                   854894

VC0000000813          BAY LINE CUTTING & CORING                             ITEM 33 (8%)

                      SAN FRANCISCO CA              809660'''
data = []
for id_, group in re.findall(
    r"(?s)BIDDER ID\D+DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED\D+(\d+)(.*?)(?=BIDDER ID|-{5,}|\Z)",
    document,
):
    items = re.findall(r"\w {3,}(.*)", group)
    data.append(
        {
            "bidder_id": id_,
            "number_subcontractors": group.count('\n\n'),
            "items": ", ".join(
                i.replace(" AND", ",").replace("ITEMS ", "").replace("ITEM", "").strip() for i in items
            ),
        }
    )

du = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But the numbers in number_subcontractors are way off. Could someone please help me understand this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: See how the `ITEM` column in the `Okay MARKING` lines on page 2 is mis-aligned. Is this just a formatting issue in your example, and all of your data is actually aligned "correctly" / is "fixed width"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is possibly "fixed width".

In which case you can extract the locations of the column names and use `pd.read_fwf` to creata a dataframe.

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

columns = [
   "BIDDER ID", "NAME AND ADDRESS", "LICENSE NUMBER", 
   "DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED"
]

pages = re.findall(
   r"(?s)LIST\s+OF\s+SUBCONTRACTORS\s+\n"
   r"(.+?)(?=\s*?CONTINUED\s+ON\s+NEXT\s+PAGE|\Z)", 
   document
)

dfs = []
for page in pages:
    header = page[:page.find("\n")]
    colspecs = [ 
       re.search(rf"(^|\s){column}(\s|$)", header).span() 
       for column in columns 
       for column in [column.replace(" ", "\s+")] 
    ]
    df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(page), colspecs=colspecs)
    df.columns = columns
    dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

You could also combine the rows, so you have a single row per "entry".

| BIDDER ID | NAME AND ADDRESS | LICENSE NUMBER | DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VC00000002 | T AND S DVBE | nan | ITEM 5 (100%) |
| nan | ANDERSON CA | 983087 | nan |
| VC00000002 | T AND S DVBE | nan | ITEM 7 (100%) |
| nan | ANDERSON CA | 983087 | nan |
| VC00000002 | T AND S DVBE | nan | ITEM 11 (100%) |
| nan | ANDERSON CA | 983087 | nan |

[...]